# functional rest api(node)test code coverage

Tags: ruby, node.js, api, cucumber, istanbul

I am trying to get code coverage for rest API endpoints written in node, but my functional(not unit) test cases calling these node end points are written in ruby and cucumber. Which approach should I use in this situation?
Thanks, appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 0):

As long as you run an instrumented version of the classes, it shouldn't matter how they are executed. The coverage logging will still be executed.

My solution would be to

- Make sure that the classes under test are properly instrumented using Cobertura or similar
- Run the test suit
- Collect all coverage files and generate a coverage report

This [blog post](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2012/02/18/test-coverage-in-a-multi-module-maven-project) describes a solution where a multi module Maven project is measured. It is somewhat related to your problem.